# Как реализовать Steam Trade бота?

Tags: node.js, steam-web-api, бот

Для этого нужны модули steam и steam-tradeoffers , но не совсем понятно как всё это делать.

Answer (score 1):

steam-web-api вам не поможет.

Есть библиотека SteamKit. Она имеет порты под разные языки.

https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/wiki/Ports
Выберите реализацию под Node.Js.

Она позволяет работать напрямую с Steam по нативному protobuff протоколу.
Т.е. реализвоать полноценную эмитацию клиента. 
Можно посмотреть готовые реализации trade ботов на других языках.

Comment: Спасибо, но я об этом и писал. Да, ошибка вышла с steam-web-api , но знаю про модуль steam. А только один модуль steam будет хватать? Смотрел на npm, steam-tradeoffers есть, получается в этом нет необходимости?

Comment: У автора node-steam (port SteamKit) на github, есть проект https://github.com/seishun/node-steam-trade.  В добавок от себя могу сказать, что на стим аккаунте для бота должна быть внесена минимальная сумма 5EUR/ для снятия ограничений. И авторизация должна осуществляться с использованием Steam Guard